# prevent sed command from writing empty file when find/replace has no match

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I want to use sed to do the following:

- Recursively find all .nfo files which **may** have a line with a unique id in them, like `<id>aa123</id>`. Each nfo has multiple lines (but only one id).
- Replace the part between the id tags with a url with the id appended to it, like `http://www.domain.com/title/aa123`.
- Remove all other lines so only `http://www.domain.com/title/aa123` remains.

I managed to piece together something that works, however when this script does not find the id string (because not all nfo file have one), I end up with an empty nfo file. How do I prevent this?

```
find /home/me/Documents -name \*.nfo -exec sed -i'.bak' -r -e '/<id>(aa[0-9]+)<\/id>/!d' -e 's/<id>(aa[0-9]+)<\/id>/http:\/\/www.domain.com\/title\/\1/' {} \;
```

Comment: Are you OK with just cleaning up the empty files afterwards? This is probably much more effective...

Comment: I am not sure, but if you put the check for zero size after the `-exec`, you may even be able to do it right there in the `find` command.

Comment: Actually no, there should be no empty files because nfo files that do not have the <id> line should remain unmodified.

Comment: OK, in that case, replace the empty file back with the `.bak` that `sed` made for you.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea but could you please show how it could be done? Perhaps in a separate answer?

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a minimally modified version of your command that handles the no-match situation separately. The advantage of this method is that you do not have to check the files twice to know if they contained the expression that you are looking for. The output of `sed` already contains that information and you are making backups, so:

```
find . -name \*.nfo \
       -exec sed -i'.bak' -r -e '/<id>(aa[0-9]+)<\/id>/!d' \
            -e 's/<id>(aa[0-9]+)<\/id>/http:\/\/www.domain.com\/title\/\1/' {} \; \
       -empty -exec mv '{}'.bak '{}' ';'
```

The bolded segment will check if the original file is empty and replace it with the backup that `sed` made. This will only happen in the no-match case, so the modified files will remain as-is.

This relies on the fact that `find` normally rearranges tests, but will preserve the meaning of the command in the order specified. From the man-page:

> The find program reorders tests to speed up execution while preserving the overall effect; that is, predicates with side effects are not reordered relative to each other.

In this case, `-exec` has a side-effect, so `-empty` will be checked after `sed` runs no matter what optimizations are done. Modified files will never be empty, so `mv` will not run in that case.

Comment: This works, thank you very much! You modified the regex a bit too much though, so I changed it back to /<id>(aa[0-9]+)<\/id>/ because I do not want the id tags in the modified nfo, only the string between those tags.

Comment: @Marc. I copied your expressions exactly, with the addition of backslashes to split the lines for readability. You can change this however it suits you.

Comment: @Marc. I see what you mean now. The tags got clobbered in the output because I used `<pre>` instead of indenting the code to get bold text in the formatted block. Fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

You have to avoid running `sed` on the files that don't have a match. You can do this with an extra `-exec` that runs `grep`; if `grep` has a non-zero exit status, that `-exec` primary fails and the rest of the primaries will not be checked for that file. (Note: this is not efficient by any stretch of the imagination.)

```
find /home/me/Documents -name '*.nfo' \
     -exec grep '<id>aa[0-9]+</id>' {} \; \
     -exec sed -i'.bak' -r \
               -e '|<id>(aa[0-9]+)</id>|!d' \
               -e 's|<id>(aa[0-9]+)</id>|http://www.domain.com/title/\1|' {} \;
```

If it still doesn't work, here's an unreadable one-line version of the above:

```
find /home/me/Documents -name '*.nfo' -exec grep '<id>(aa[0-9]+)</id>' {} \; -exec sed -i'.bak' -r -e '|<id>(aa[0-9]+)</id>|!d' -e 's|<id>(aa[0-9]+)</id>|http://www.domain.com/title/\1|' {} \;
```

Comment: Pasting this in a terminal gives me a bunch of errors. Do I add it to a .sh shell script and make it executable? I tried this but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I had some annoyingly invisible spaces after one of the backslashes that I've removed. It (or the one-line equivalent that I added) should work now.

Comment: No more errors, but nothing happens. The nfo files are not modifed and no bak file is created.

Comment: I forgot to remove the parentheses from the `grep` regex after copying it from `sed` (`grep` doesn't need a capture group).

Comment: Oh I see, are you sure that should cause it to fail though? I removed it but still no luck.

Comment: @chepner. I didn't see your comment in the answer. Removed mine.

Comment: @MadPhysicist (I'd have to benchmark, but running `grep` might still be faster than unnecessarily writing an empty copy, since `sed` is still reading the entire file in the process.)

Comment: @chepner. I can't imagine that it would be slower, since all `sed` is doing is opening a new file for writing. It is not truncating or anything like that. I don't think the `mv` costs much either since it is within the same directory and the file being deleted is empty. But like you said, it would be nice to see a benchmark.

Comment: After thinking some more, I think you're right. `grep` can stop reading early, but `sed` writes very little (and those writes are likely buffered in memory), meaning little or no disk I/O actually occurs until after `find` completes (and the `mv` could actually "cancel" the writes.)